# golang echart paralle coordinates with more than one string axis

Tags: go, echarts

i am using this code https://github.com/go-echarts/examples/blob/master/examples/parallel.go to generate a parabox chart which have the following fields :

User,Product,Shop

which are strings
my Data structures represented below  :

```
 parallelAxisList = []opts.ParallelAxis{
        
        {Dim: 0, Name: "User", Type: "category"},
        {Dim: 1, Name: "Product", Type: "category"},
        {Dim: 2, Name: "Shop", Type: "category"}
    }

parallelData = [][]interface{}{
        {"user1","product1","shop1"},
        {"user1","product2","shop1"},
        {"user1","product2","shop2"},
        {"user2","product1","shop2"},
        {"user1","product1","shop2"},
        
        }
```

but for some reason the graph render only with the first axis shown (i.e user1 and user2 but the other axises empty) any idea?

if I am replacing the second and third columns of `parallelData` with numeric values and remove the category type of product and shop on `parallelAxisList` it rendering good , any idea how to render strings fields ?